# Typescript fails to update view in HTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I've been working working on an app, which passes in user event posts from MongoDB and renders them in HTML:

**Event-post.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {

this.postsService.getPosts();
this.postSub = this.postsService.getPostUpDateListener()
.subscribe((posts: Post[]) => {
  this.posts = posts;
```

**Event-post.html**

```
 <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let post of posts">
<!-- Display event posts -->
```

This works fine. However, recently I decided to create an additional function, which allows users to filter the events according to proximity to their location. Users enter their postcode and select a distance from a drop down menu. The data passes through a series of calculations; convert postcode to lat/lng, calculate distance between point and finally, filter according to required distance.

```
receivePost($event) {
    this.postFilter = $event;

/****************** Convert Event Posts to LAT LNG **********************************/
this.eventPostcode = [];
console.log('Incoming POSTS: ', this.posts);
for (let i = 0; i < this.posts.length; i++) {
  this.geoCodingService.geocodeAddress(this.posts[i].postcode)
  .subscribe(
    location => {
      this.lat = location.lat;
      this.lng = location.lng;
      const e: EventPostcode = {lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng};
      this.eventPostcode.push(e);
     /* console.log('TEST: ', this.eventPostcode);*/
    }
  );
}

/****************** Convert reference post to LAT LNG **************************/
 this.myPostcode = [];
this.geoCodingService.geocodeAddress(this.postFilter)
.subscribe(
  location => {
    this.lat = location.lat;
    this.lng = location.lng;
    const m: MyPostcode = {lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng};
    this.myPostcode.push(m);
    this.calcDist();
  }
);
}

/******************** Calculate distance between each point **********************/

calcDist() {
const posts = [];

const haversineCalculator = require('haversine-calculator');
for ( let i = 0; i < this.eventPostcode.length; i++) {
const start = {
  latitude: this.myPostcode[0].lat,
  longitude: this.myPostcode[0].lng
};
const end = {
  latitude: this.eventPostcode[i].lat,
  longitude: this.eventPostcode[i].lng
};

/***** Filter according to distance (Options: 15, 25, 50 miles) */
 if (haversineCalculator( start, end, {unit: 'mile'}) < this.distFilter) {
 console.log(haversineCalculator( start, end, {unit: 'mile'}));
   posts.push(this.posts[i]);
 }

 }
 console.log('Filtered posts: ', posts);

 this.posts = posts;
}
```

The problems occurs when I try to update the new list in my view. If I comment out this.posts = posts, effectively disabling HTML rendering, and examine the filtered array via console.log('Filtered posts', posts), everything works fine. The posts are filtered exactly how I want. But soon as I try to render the data in my view, everything falls apart.

Although there are no apparent errors showing in the console, when I activate the event handler, the process performs agonisingly slow, and takes about 8 seconds to eventually update the view.

In addition to this problem, when I examine the posts being passed from the database (this.posts) into the event handler, they diminish each time I press enter. So, if I start with 6 events from the database and filter down to 3, the next time the event is fired, only 3 events are available.

I'd really appreciate any guidance anyone may have regarding this issue. 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by "everything falls apart" ?

Comment: Have you tried storing and keeping the original posts intact and introduce a filteredPosts variable to be rendered by the view?

Comment: If you need data received from an observable in another observable, you need use SwitchMap or forkJoin to "concatenate" observables (else can happens the second observable finish before the first). In your case, when you call to function calcDist, it's possible you have no eventPostcode values

Answer (score 0):

> In addition to this problem, when I examine the posts being passed from the database (this.posts) into the event handler, they diminish each time I press enter. So, if I start with 6 events from the database and filter down to 3, the next time the event is fired, only 3 events are available.

When you call `calcDist()` you update `this.post` with the new, filtered posts. When you call `receivePost()`, you simple use `this.post` without resetting it. So each time you call `calcDist()` you're potentially reducing the length of `this.post` and you never appear to reset `this.post` to it's original length. This would explain why each time you filter events the number of events seem to get permanently smaller.

I'm also not sure why you are saving post `lat` and `lng` to class variables, as those class variables will only every contain the last value they are given. I.e. you are iterating through an array and overwriting `this.lat` and `this.lng` each time. Because the observables are executing asyncronously, you aren't even guarenteed of the order their callback functions will be called in. You really have no idea what the final value of `this.lat` and `this.lng` will be.

Finally, observables pinging an api are async functions. You appear to be relying on them to execute synchronously because you call `this.calcDist()` at the end of the `this.geoCodingService.geocodeAddress(this.postFilter)` subscription callback. But, for all you know, that callback might execute before any of the `this.geoCodingService.geocodeAddress(this.posts[i].postcode)` callbacks. Meaning that `this.eventPosts` could have a length of 0 when `this.calcDist()` is called (even when there *are* event posts).

One possible solution, convert your observables to promises and use `await` to ensure the order of execution is what you want it to be.

Example:

```js
async receivePost($event) {

  this.postFilter = $event;
  // as I mentioned, you need some way of resetting posts to get rid of old filtering
  this.posts = originalPosts;

  /****************** Convert Event Posts to LAT LNG **********************************/
  this.eventPostcode = [];

  const geocodedEventLocations = await Promise.all(
    this.posts.map(post => 
      this.geoCodingService.geocodeAddress(post.postcode).toPromise()
    )
  );

  geocodedEventLocations.forEach(location => {
    this.eventPostcode.push({
      lat: location.lat,
      lng: location.lng,
    })
  });

  /****************** Convert reference post to LAT LNG **************************/
  this.myPostcode = undefined; // not sure why you were setting this to an array before...

  const postFilterLocation =
    await this.geoCodingService.geocodeAddress(this.postFilter).toPromise();

  this.myPostcode = {
    lat: postFilterLocation.lat,
    lng: postFilterLocation.lng,
  };

  this.calcDist();
}


/******************** Calculate distance between each point **********************/

calcDist() {
  const posts = [];

  const haversineCalculator = require('haversine-calculator');

  this.eventPostcode.forEach((eventPostcode, index) => {
    const start = {
      latitude: this.myPostcode.lat,
      longitude: this.myPostcode.lng
    };

    const end = {
      latitude: eventPostcode.lat,
      longitude: eventPostcode.lng
    };

    /***** Filter according to distance (Options: 15, 25, 50 miles) */
    if (haversineCalculator( start, end, {unit: 'mile'}) < this.distFilter) {
      posts.push(this.posts[index]);
    }  
  })

   this.posts = posts;
}
```

I haven't tested this example, and there might well be other problems, but hopefully you get the idea.

Finally, I'll assume there's a reason why you are setting

```
const haversineCalculator = require('haversine-calculator');
```

inside the `calcDist()` method call instead of simply using

```
import * as haversineCalculator from 'haversine-calculator';
```

at the top of the file (or even `const haversineCalculator = require('haversine-calculator');` at the top of the file).

Comment: Thanks John... most appreciated. It would appear I need learn more about async functions. Everything is working fine now apart from GoogleMaps API throwing a OVER_QUERY_LIMIT status error if I exceed the number of requests per second. Having searched other posts on this site, it appears this is a common problem and  some solutions suggest implementing a delay within the geocoding process to combat this issue. Thanks again for your time John.